# Difference between week of year and week of year ISO tokens (moment.js)

Tags: momentjs

I was studying date formating in moment.js and I came across these tokens:
Is there any significant difference between `WoY` and `WoY ISO`?

Week of Year

```
w - 1 2 ... 52 53  
wo - 1st 2nd ... 52nd 53rd  
ww - 01 02 ... 52 53
```

Week of Year (ISO)

```
W - 1 2 ... 52 53  
Wo - 1st 2nd ... 52nd 53rd  
WW - 01 02 ... 52 53
```

Comment: It seems that they differentiate by the way they handle starting day of the week. If I am using ISO token than starting day is considered monday, otherwise it defaults to my locale setting which is Sunday.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), the ISO week counter starts the first thursday of the year; so, if the first day of the year is saturday, the first thursday will be in the next week.

Thus, the ISO week of the first thursday will be the first, but the standard week of the first thursday will be the second, e.g.

```
moment('2005-01-02').isoWeek(); // 53
moment('2005-01-02').week(); // 1
moment('2005-01-03').isoWeek(); // 1
moment('2005-01-03').week(); // 2
```

Regards!

Comment: Also, ISO weeks start on Monday. "Standard" weeks may start on any day of the week depending on custom. Saturday, Sunday and Monday are common, there are likely others.

Comment: The answer is correct but a little bit confusing. I would rephrase it as `the ISO week counter starts from the week with the first Thursday of the year. So, if the first day of the year is Saturday, it belongs to the last week of the previous year.`