# Moment.js returning unexpected year

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I’m struggling with the new year 2017 in my web app using moment.js.

When I’m writing:

```
moment('2017-01-03').isoWeekYear(2016).week(52); // results = Dec 27 2015
```

meanwhile when i write:

```
moment('2017-01-04').isoWeekYear(2016).week(52); //results = Dec 26 2016
```

My expectation is that both of these should give me the answer "Dec 26 2016". Probably I’m thinking wrong or could this be a bug in moment.js?

I have struggled for a while to come up with an answer or a workaround without any success..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120122/difference-between-week-of-year-and-week-of-year-iso-tokens-moment-js?

Comment: Are you using current (2.17.1) moment.js?

Comment: @user01 my current version is 2.8.4

Comment: Have you given the current a try? My quick tests showed answers that match what you want.

Comment: Updating moment.js from 2.8.4 to 2.17.1 did solv the problem. Thanks @user01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an up to date version of moment.js? Something is off, because here's what I get when I run your moment.js code:

```js
console.log(moment('2017-01-03').isoWeekYear(2016).week(52));
console.log(moment('2017-01-04').isoWeekYear(2016).week(52));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
"2016-12-20T05:00:00.000Z"
"2016-12-21T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Updating moment.js from 2.8.4 to 2.17.1 did solv the problem. Thanks @user01