# What is the difference between isoWeek and week?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using moment to check if a day falls within a certain week and my test case is failing on a difference between `isoWeek` and `week` for the dates `2020-04-11` and `2020-04-12`. When I use `isoWeek` they are in the same week and when I use `week` they are not. The documentation in moment points to a wikipedia page and from what I understand this `isoWeek` takes leap years into consideration so that there might be fewer days in a leap year and therefore these dates would not land in the same week bounds.

Can someone explain the difference between `week` and `isoWeek` to me?

Comment: Do you have checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120122/difference-between-week-of-year-and-week-of-year-iso-tokens-moment-js/32187855 ?

Comment: @ManishSundriyal Ahh I did not see that when I was googling, thank you!

Comment: No problem, I have marked it as a duplicate for now.
Does this answer your question? [Difference between week of year and week of year ISO tokens (moment.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120122/difference-between-week-of-year-and-week-of-year-iso-tokens-moment-js)